# Magento configuring email on Gmail

Tags: magento, email, ssl, smtp, gmail

I have configured **app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php**:

```
$config = array(
           'ssl' => 'tls', 
           'port' => Mage::getStoreConfig('system/smtp/port'), // it is set to 25
           'auth' => 'login', 
           'username' => 'email@gmail.com',
           'name' => Mage::getStoreConfig('system/smtp/host'), // it is set to smtp.gmail.com
           'password' => 'password'
       );
```

but im still getting exception :

**Unable to send mail. mail(): SMTP server response: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first**

where else I need to make changes to make it work? It is somewhere else than **app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php** ?

Comment: Only difference in your way from mine is that i'm not using 'ssl' => 'tls', in this array. What if you remove this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Described config is functional, for viewing changes in scripts is needed to turn off Magento compiler an clean /includes/folder.

There is changed email function supporting Google Gmail or Google Apps:

1 copy file "**app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php**" to "**app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php**"

2 In file app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Email/**Template.php** change function:

```
public function getMail()
{
    if (is_null($this->_mail)) {
    $my_smtp_host = Mage::getStoreConfig('system/smtp/host');
    $my_smtp_port = Mage::getStoreConfig('system/smtp/port');
    $config = array(
              'port' => $my_smtp_port,
              'auth' => 'login',
              'ssl' => 'tls',
              'username' => 'youremail@gmail.com',
              'password' => 'Abc'
              );
     $transport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp($my_smtp_host,$config);
     Zend_Mail::setDefaultTransport($transport);         





        $this->_mail = new Zend_Mail('utf-8');
    }
    return $this->_mail;
}
```

Disable compiler, rename folder /includes/ in magento root and clear cache

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be make change to core.

Instead create a custom module, take a look @ [Use any SMTP to send mail in Magento](http://magentocommerceblog.blogspot.com/2011/12/send-mail-through-gmail-or-other-server.html)

Take a look at [Send email in magento using your GMail or Google Apps account](https://github.com/magepal/GmailSmtpApp)

Comment: I make changes at app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php, But problem is that changes arent affected, even in app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php, there are no other modules, where can be point?

Comment: It always better (in my opinion) to create a custom module instead of rewriting thing using 'local/Mage'

Comment: Also I think Gmail SMTP port is 465 and not port 25 .. http://email.about.com/od/accessinggmail/f/Gmail_SMTP_Settings.htm

Comment: Solved, after hours, needed to turn of compiler and rename /Includes/ folder. Changes start to be functional, config is right.

Comment: Your answer is right but not clear, i write a full answer below.